# Stop Integration Runtimes in Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am figuring out to stop integration runtime in Data Factory; it is not terminated even after inactivity and is burning money.

Can someone suggest me anything?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What type of IR and what type of activities are using it?

Comment: AutoResolveIntegrationRuntime that comes default with the data factory. It is always running. I learnt that we cannot stop it. Now the question is, does Microsoft charge for it all the time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is the default Azure IR that comes with every factory. It contains configuration information used by activities so that it can use the proper compute environment for copy, data flow, external activities, etc. You are only billed when you are executing those activities or using debug.